# PhpMyadmin added additions parameter in Select Query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have tried to run a select query in phpmyadmin Sql tab as below

```
Select * from followers
```

I just run above query alone

But it return following Error in the image, can anybody help to fix this issue?  can you tell me in what case it will happends?

[image]

Comment: Parenthesis not opens but closes, WHERE clause missing instead you use AND.

Answer (score 0):

You should use comma for adding others column in order by

```
     Select * from followers
     order  by  follwer_id DESC, leader_id 
     limit 30
```

or if you want filter the query you  should use where

```
     Select * from followers
     where leader_id =1
     order  by  follwer_id
     limit 30
```

Comment: i just wanted to run select * table query, not order by or filter

Comment: Could be you have  .. some query saved  .. then  before you type the new query  text `Select * from followers`  be sure you  have  cleared  the sql  tab input textarea

Comment: How will it be saved before? I just run 'Select * from followers' only in the box

Comment: each time you execute a query or phpmyadmin execute a query for show a result  the query is stored .. you can see this query  .. pressing the button  below the textarea for  Get the query auto memorized or somethings similar